# Updating cassandra collections from spark

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-cassandra-connector

I am pretty new to spark-cassandra.

I am going through the documentation of spark-casssandra connector to figure out how to update cassandra collections.
This link(https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md) has the following code to update collections:

```scala
val listElements = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1,Vector("One")),
  (1,Vector("Two")),
  (1,Vector("Three"))))

val prependElements = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1,Vector("PrependOne")),
  (1,Vector("PrependTwo")),
  (1,Vector("PrependThree"))))

listElements.saveToCassandra("ks", "collections_mod", SomeColumns("key", "lcol" append))
prependElements.saveToCassandra("ks", "collections_mod", SomeColumns("key", "lcol" prepend))
```

But when i try the above code in eclipse, i get an error near "lcol" append and "lcol" prepend

Error is :  value append is not a member of String
and
 value prepend is not a member of String

Am i missing anything here? How do i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add `import com.datastax.spark.connector._` to your code. This will bring an implicit conversion from `String` to `ColumnName` in your scope. `ColumnName` has the sought operations `prepend` and `append` available.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Upgrading `sbt` plugin to `"com.datastax.spark"  %% "spark-cassandra-connector"  % "1.5.0-RC1"` version and ran `./activator clean` helped